# API endpoint provides StackOverFlow error with multiple calls

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an API provided:

```
@GetMapping("/createarmy/{size}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getCastleArmyByTotalSize(@PathVariable(value = "size")@Positive(message = "total size needs to be great than 0") int size) {

        try {
            Castle castle = castleService.createArmy(size);

            if (castle != null) {

                return new ResponseEntity<>(castle, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
            }

            return new ResponseEntity<>(ApiResponseMessage.getGenericApiResponse(Boolean.FALSE, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                MessageConstant.RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND_MSG), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(MessageConstant.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_MSG + ex.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(ApiResponseMessage.getInternalServerError(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

The service is implemnetd as below:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class CastleService {


    @Autowired
    private CastleCache castleCache;

    @Autowired
    private CastleRepository castleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;


    /**
     * create different types of army based on the size
     *
     * @param sizeOfArmy
     * @return
     */
    @SneakyThrows
    public synchronized Castle createArmy(int sizeOfArmy) {


        if (castleCache.getStore().size() == 100) {

            castleCache.getStore().clear();
        }

        int total = sizeOfArmy;

        Random rand = new Random();

        Map<TroopTypes, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

        int enumSize = TroopTypes.values().length;

        int typesNumber = -1;

        do {
            typesNumber = rand.nextInt(enumSize + 1);
        }

        while (typesNumber < MIN_NUMBER_OF_TYPES || typesNumber == enumSize);

        int temp;

        for (int i = 0; i <= typesNumber - 1; i++) {

            TroopTypes unitType = getNextUnitTypes(rand, enumSize, map);

            if (typesNumber - 1 == i) {

                map.put(unitType, sizeOfArmy);
                break;
            }

            temp = rand.nextInt(sizeOfArmy + 1);
            map.put(unitType, temp);

            sizeOfArmy -= temp;
        }

        map.values().removeIf(value -> value == 0);

        if (castleCache.getStore().contains(map) || map.size() < MIN_NUMBER_OF_TYPES) {

            log.info("We get the same result previously and need to repeat the computation.");
            map.clear();

            Thread.sleep(1000);

            return createArmy(sizeOfArmy);
        }

        castleCache.getStore().add(map);

        CastleDto castleDto = new CastleDto();

        castleDto.setTotalSize(total);
        castleDto.setTypeAndSizeMap(map);

        Castle castle = modelMapper.map(castleDto, Castle.class);

        return castle;
    }

    private static TroopTypes getNextUnitTypes(Random rand, int enumSize, Map<TroopTypes, Integer> map) {

        while (true) {

            int index = rand.nextInt(enumSize);
            TroopTypes unitType = TroopTypes.values()[index];

            if (!map.containsKey(unitType)) {

                return unitType;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This works well, but when I make frequent calls, I get the StackOverFlow error from the line:

```
return createArmy(sizeOfArmy);
```

This is the error stack if I remove the thread sleep:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1075) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:84) ~[logback-core-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:51) ~[logback-core-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:270) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:257) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:421) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Logger.java:579) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.castle.creator.service.CastleService.createArmy(CastleService.java:84) ~[classes/:na]
```

I am thinking to use RxJava Observable to enqueue/deque data and release, but not sure how to write it.

How do I implement it better to prevent that to happen?

Comment: How about stacktrace? stackoverflow suggests circular reference or recursion somewhere.

Comment: @rkosegi updated the question with an error stack